# Offset vs Alignment in Flutter

Tags: flutter, alignment, offset, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Although I know their uses and properties but sometimes I found it hard to tell the difference between `Offset` and `Alignment` as both of them represents a point in `x-axis` and `y-axis`

Comment: `Alignment` is handy when you want to place a child within its parent (for example on center-left position) and you dont have to know both parent's and child's bounding box sizes

Answer (score 3):

For others out there:
According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html,
The equation for alignment to offset is:

```
offsetX = alignmentX * width/2 + width/2
offsetY = alignmentY * height/2 + height/2
```

So using some algebra, to go the other way and convert an offset to an alignment is:

```
alignmentX = (offsetX - width/2)/(width/2)
alignmentY = (offsetY - height/2)/(height/2)
```

Where width and height is the width/height of the parent the offset is based on (like the window/screen if using global coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

[Offset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html) uses coordinates for the object's location. [Alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html) on the other hand still uses coordinates, but Parent widgets is used as the basis for the coordinates.